# Normal distribution with real standard deviation

Tags: system-verilog, normal-distribution

I need to generate a normal distribution variable with standard deviation as real.
I understand that `$dist_normal` only expects integers.

How can I use real type arguments?

I have tried using the Verilog-A `$rdist_normal` and failed compilation.
Other than that, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Scale and shift the integer output of `$dist_normal` using real values:

```
module tb;

int seed, randint;
real randreal;
initial begin
    seed = 1;
    repeat (20) begin
        randint  = $dist_normal(seed, 100, 10);
        randreal = 200.0 + (randint/5.0);
        $display("%.2f", randreal);
    end
end

endmodule
```

---

Syntax that is specific to [Verilog-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog-A) can not be used with SystemVerilog; think of them as different languages.